# Get specific form of range in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

When getting `range(1,100)` I get:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 99 ]
```

I need something like zip of this range:

```
[ 50, 49, 51, 48, 52, 47, 53 ... 99 ]
```

How to get it?

---

**Background**: It is all about Bitcoin puzzle 66.

First I made prediction with linear regression for past known private keys till puzzle 65 including. I put puzzle 66 and two following as the prediction I want to get. I got three integer numbers.

Now I don't want to search from `number-1M` to `number+1M` because I might be closer to the real private key with the original number, so I need to search from the middle. And that's what the answer is needed for.

Comment: What have you tried? You have some sequence of values and you want to collect those values, starting in the middle, alternating taking from the left and the right, and you've already identified that `zip` may help - please share a code example of what you tried and how the result was surprising to you.

Comment: What are the parameters? I.e., what numbers do you have that shall be turned into such a sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can assign to list slices:

```py
out = [0] * 99
out[::2], out[1::2] = range(50, 100), range(49, 0, -1)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[50, 49, 51, 48, 52, ... 2, 98, 1, 99]
```

Comment: Cute, I like this one. Should be fairly efficient to boot.

Comment: You're wasting a line! Can just do `out, out[::2], out[1::2] = [0] * 99, range(50, 100), range(49, 0, -1)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Pshaw, still too verbose, you say `out` three whole times! `(out:=[0]*99)[::2], out[1::2] = range(50, 100), range(49, 0, -1)`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Shedding two more chars: `(out:=[0]*99)[::2], out[~1::-2] = range(50, 100), range(1, 50)`

Comment: Maybe nicer order: `(out:=[0]*99)[~1::-2], out[::2] = range(1, 50), range(50, 100)`

Answer (score 1):

Without relying on imports, you can mock this up with a fairly simple list comprehension:

```
[x for i in range(50) for x in {50-i:0,50+i:0}]
```

It does do a little extra work to avoid the doubled `50` (relying on `dict` preserving order and deduping in 3.6+), which can be avoided by using a generator expression that you discard the first value of, or a listcomp you delete the first element of, after which it produces the values only building (cheap) two-`tuple`s, rather than (more expensive) `dict`s (that said, generator expressions have higher overhead themselves, so you'd test for which solution works best for you):

```
nums = (x for i in range(50) for x in (50-i, 50+i))
next(nums)  # Throw away first copy of 50
nums = list(nums)

# Or as a listcomp that immediately slices off the known duplicate value
nums = [x for i in range(50) for x in (50-i, 50+i)][1:]

# Or just for fun, slice the `tuple` in a way that only slices the first one, so no copies of the list are involved
nums = [x for i in range(50) for x in (50-i, 50+i)[:i+1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
[50 - i//2 * (-1)**i
 for i in range(1, 100)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3rQqKMvNKNKJNDRR0FTL19Y0UtBQ0dA01tbQyuRQgIC2_SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1BHwdDAQDNWE2IC1CCYgQA)

Answer (score 0):

using `zip` and `range` function, you desire pattern reqiure you to show result together with two different sequences, which are `50, 51, 52 ...99` and `49,48,...1` one by one together.

use `range` function to generate the sequences and zip function to bind them together and `print` to show result.

below is a basic implementation

```
>>> start = 1
>>> end = 100
>>> mid = start + (start + end)//2
>>> mid
51
>>>
>>> sequence_1 = [i for i in range(mid-1, 0,-1)]
>>> sequence_1
[50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41, 40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> sequence_2 = [i for i in range(mid, end+1)]
>>> sequence_2
[51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
>>>
>>>
>>> len(sequence_1)
50
>>> len(sequence_2)
50
>>> for a, b in zip(sequence_2, sequence_1):
...     print(a, b, end='\t')
...
51 50   52 49   53 48   54 47   55 46   56 45   57 44   58 43   59 42   60 41   61 40   62 39   63 38   64 37   65 36  66 35    67 34   68 33   69 32   70 31   71 30   72 29   73 28   74 27   75 26   76 25   77 24   78 23   79 22   80 21  81 20    82 19   83 18   84 17   85 16   86 15   87 14   88 13   89 12   90 11   91 10   92 9    93 8    94 7    95 6   96 5     97 4    98 3    99 2    100 1   
>>>
```

Comment: The math here is off, and `zip` causes issues; you're missing `98` and `1` due to the math issue, and `zip` causes problems for odd length outputs making it non-trivial to add the also missing `99` without also adding `0`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes you are right, zip need equal length sequence and range take end as exclsive which make it a tricker